# Set same height for icons and text in Libgdx

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx

I want to draw a score bar like shown below. Score text length varies as score is accumulated. The bar size should be 0.075*screen height.

1) How do I set height for start texture and fonts with respect to score bar height. This should work in all screen sizes.

2) Also how do I draw a orange rectangle, where it width varies based on score length in libgdx.

[image]

My code is shows below.

```
public class ScoreBar {

    float totalTime = 0;
    long totalScore = 0;
    float scoreLen = 10;
    float scoreHeight = 10;
    String timeString = "0:00";
    String scoreString = "0";
    int hours =0;
    int minutes =0;
    int seconds =0;

    float width;
    float height;
    BitmapFont font;
    float top = 0;
    float tmargin = 10;
    float hmargin = 20;
    Texture starIcon;
    Texture clockIcon;
    float barHeight  =10;
    float iconSize = 10;

    public ScoreBar(BitmapFont scoreFont, float width, float height, Texture star, Texture clock){
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.font = scoreFont;
        font.setColor(1, 0, 0, 1);

        barHeight = height * .075f;
        tmargin = barHeight * 0.2f;
        hmargin = barHeight * 0.5f;
        iconSize = barHeight - 2*tmargin;
        top = height - tmargin/2;
        starIcon = star;
        clockIcon = clock;
    }

    public void render(SpriteBatch batch){
        batch.draw(starIcon, hmargin, top - iconSize, iconSize, iconSize);
        batch.draw(clockIcon, width*0.65f, top - iconSize,  iconSize, iconSize);
        font.draw(batch, scoreString, hmargin + iconSize + tmargin, top - scoreHeight);
        font.draw(batch, timeString, width*0.65f + tmargin + iconSize, top - scoreHeight);
    }
```

Comment: Please explain why / how your code doesn't work. Your question is too general.

Comment: I want Font height to be icon height. How do I set the font size or height without recalculating width, also question two, how do I draw a rectangle

Comment: How is this question related to opengl-es?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `ShapeRenderer` to draw your orange rectangle. Here's a [link](http://:%20http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShapeRenderer.html) to the documentation. They put in sample code there so I won't reiterate over that again. If you want it's width to vary over the score you can code some simple updating of the rectangle width.

```
if(score > 100){
    rectWidth = 25;
} elif (score > 200){
    rectWidth = 35;
}
```

For your icon use a simple `SpriteBatch` to draw your icon over the orange rectangle.

For all this font height business, experiment with the fonts and find one that covers the height of the icon well and then adjust the width of the rectangle accordingly.

If this doesn't work you could create your own font, scale something etc.

The height of these textures shouldn't change at run-time so just experiment before and find something that works!

I hope this answer helped you! If you have any further questions please feel free to comment below!

Comment: do you mean do couple of bitmapFont.getData().setScale(float x, float y)  tests and compare it against the icon hieght during initialization?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. Once you get the right font size or scale on the font you can then just worry about the icon's width.